# What are all the angular-cli.json Options?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need to update the `angular-cli.json` configuration settings for an `@angular/cli` project that I inherited, but the [Angular-CLI Wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/) does not have any information on the content of that JSON file, nor the available options.

How do I get a list of all properties available in the `angular-cli.json` configuration settings?

The closest thing seems to be [this `ng get` documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/config), but that assumes that I *know* all the properties.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the documentation you are looking for is here:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli

Comment: This is old. I believe they updated this but I can't seem to find it in the documentation

Comment: @Phil: If you are looking for the schema of _angular.json_, it's [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace).